# Form validation using fetch response not working?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to do some form validation by checking to see if the user credentials already exist in our database by using a fetch request and getting back the success status, but when I try it with an existing user it forwards me to the new page regardless, is there a solution for this or a better way of doing it

HTML code

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateUser()" method="post">
   <label style="padding-bottom: 0px;" class="form-label">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="usrname" name="usrname" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
   <label style="padding-top: 10px;" class="form-label">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" required class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Password">
<button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
function validateUser() {
    let email = document.forms["myform"]["usrname"].value;
    let pass = document.forms["myform"]["psw"].value;
    var formattedEmail = email.replace("@", "%40");
    var status;
    var URL = `${baseURL}/sign_in?email=${formattedEmail}&password=${pass}`;
    fetch(URL,{method: 'POST'}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
    if(data.status== true){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "this email was already used";
        return false; 
    }else{
        //make the user account 
        //forward to the new page
  } 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

Comment: Your if condition gets executed before your fetch call finishes. So status is always false whenever the if condition gets executed regardless of your user existing or not. You need to put the if condition in a `.then` or use async await to make the execution of fetch call synchronous.

Comment: @Nilanshu96 tried that but still the same result

Comment: @Mas_T can  you try doing `async function validateUser() { return await fetch() {} }`.

Comment: @Nilanshu96 — The code depends on `validateUser` returning a boolean, making it async will make it return a promise.

Comment: @Quentin yes I see that but the original code is also not returning anything. The returned boolean inside fetch call would get lost as the function would end before fetch call is finished but despite that the page is redirecting so I think more clarification would be needed here.

Comment: @Nilanshu96 I used a different solution entirely i had to do something like this ``` $('document').ready(() => {
  $("#signUpForm").submit((e) => {
    validateUser()
    return false;
  });
}); ```

Comment: @Mas_T Good job figuring out the solution!